# Torque of a rotating fluid on a weighing scale

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I was trying to do an experiment to measure torque (Moment force) of a rotating fluid. 
I placed a cylindrical vessel of dia-12cm with 1liter of water on a weighing scale and using a spoon I rotated to my anticlockwise at quiet good speed to find any change in the weight on the scale. I did find change in weight when I dipped my spoon in the liquid, but no change in the weight of liquid during water moving around(Without spoon). Why is that? There should be change in weight (increase) due to moment force (Torque) which is directing towards weighing scale as per right hand rule for torque right...?you can see a whirl in the middle of the vessel which says the torque is at the center but force?.
[image]

Comment: You know gravity is still acting on the fluid, and that is what your are measuring.

Comment: I know the weight of liquid is mass times gravity.my question is where is the moment force in my weighing scale while swirling the water?

Comment: The motion occurs on a different plane than what you are measuring forces at. Even if there was an effect (there isn't since a pure torque does not move the center of gravity) you woun't measure it with a scale.

Comment: i am sorry,i dint understand.if right hand rule is true,why wouldnt i see the force?also a force can be measured using a weigning scale right?i am swirling the entire water,so i can clearly see water is rotating from top to bottom.its height is almost 10cm..are you explaining me that the force will be too small to measure in a weighing scale?please make it clear.

Comment: Is the axis of rotation vertical or horizontal? You need to clarify that in the OP. Are you stirring a pot, or is it like a cement mixer?

Comment: axis of rotation is horizontal.i am stirring the water in the pot  from top using a spoon.

Comment: So the axis is vertical then. Right? Line up and down you are rotating _about_. The plane of motion is horizontal, but the axis is vertical along gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, there should be no change in weight if the fluid is rotating. The scale measures total **force** acting on the system (including inertial loading). But a pure rotation does not accelerate the center of gravity in the direction measured so there is no effect. Ask yourself, is the CG of the system moving vertically?

When you place the spoon in, you are applying an external force to the system, and you are measuring the component of that force in the vertical direction.